# Inviting people to proofread a mathematical text allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently wrote a short introduction to the Lebesgue-Integral, following a path that was outlined in a German textbook on functional-analysis, but without any proofs there. The approach is probably a bit idiosyncratic but I think not without value.

Now I would like to invite potential readers to (proof)read the text, as I am not at an university and have no people among my friends or acquaintances who could take a look. Would that be allowed in the form of a question on math.stackexchange? If not, what could be an alternative to find some readers?

Comment: About 17 pages (DIN A4).

Comment: A near duplicate of [Are review questions on topic?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21326/are-review-questions-on-topic) Key part for the present case "if you link to a twenty page pdf somewhere, this might not go over so well."

Comment: This is also somewhat similar: [Submitting a paper for review](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4125) - although it is a bit different since you are not asking about a paper.

Comment: I would not give it too much chance, but suitable place to ask might be chat. You could try [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics), [analysis chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14150/calculus-and-analysis) and perhaps even [MathOverflow chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9369/mathoverflow). (And in case you find some people interested in the project, it is conceivable that you will create a separate chat room for that purpose.)